# Como usar AJAX que pegue o valor de um campo para um select e retorne para uma modal em uma partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, modal, view

Meu código aqui:

View:

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.lNaoIncluidos.Count; i++){
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Informações do BIC"><i class="fa fa-info-circle btnModal"></i></span>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.lNaoIncluidos[i].ID_Info)</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
     }
</tbody>
```

Ao clicar no ícone que tem a classe btnModal na primeira "td", gostaria de chamar um AJAX para fazer um select e trazer outras informações com base no ID_Info. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua linha da View, coloque a ação `onclick="Search()"`

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Informações do BIC"><i class="fa fa-info-circle btnModal" onclick="Search()"></i></span>
```

javaScript:

```
function Search() {

    var prametro = 'teste';

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")', //Aqui, coloque o nome o seu método no primeiro parametro e o nome da controller no segundo parametro
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { nomeDoParametro: prametro }, //Coloque os parametros (caso precise).
    success: function (result) {
        //programe aqui seu callBack (retorno da controller)
    }
   });
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Search(string parametro)
{
    //Programe aqui sua busca

    return Json(true/*retorne aqui sua busca*/ , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //O AllowGet é necessário para que seu método permita requisições GET a este método.
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!